# Problem Creating table in the database

Tags: magento-2.1, php

I'm following [this](http://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/add-a-new-table-to-database/) tutorial to create a new table inside the database.

From the tutorial, I've followed till Step 4. I can verify that a the new module is created after running `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`, but no table named `greeting_message` is created for me.

I guess, The database here refers to the database I created while Installing Magento. I've seen all the tables of the database from phpmyadmin but there is no database named `greeting_message`.

Where am I going Wrong?

**InstallData.php**

```
<?php


    namespace Learning\GreetingMessage\Setup;

    use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

    /**
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
    {

      /**
       * {@inheritdoc}
       * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
       * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
       * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
       */
      public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
      {
        /**
         * Install messages
         */
        $data = [
             ['message' => 'Happy New Year'],
             ['message' => 'Marry Christams']
             ];
        foreach ($data as $bind) {
          $setup->getConnection()
        ->insertForce($setup->getTable('greeting_message'), $bind);
        }
      }
    }
```

**InstallSchema.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Learning\GreetingMessage\Setup;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
   */
  public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
  {
    /**
     * Create table 'greeting_message'
     */
    $table = $setup->getConnection()
      ->newTable($setup->getTable('greeting_message'))
      ->addColumn(
                  'greeting_id',
                  \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                  null,
                  ['identity' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
                  'Greeting ID'
          )
      ->addColumn(
                  'message',
                  \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                  255,
                  ['nullable' => false, 'default' => ''],
          'Message'
          )->setComment("Greeting Message table");
    $setup->getConnection()->createTable($table);
  }
}
```

Comment: post your InstallData.php file of your module

Comment: It's same as mentioned on the page with prefix <?php. Added above.

Comment: so when you run command setup:upgrade - its not creating table ?

Comment: yes, it's not creating table.

Comment: did you checked any error in logs?

Comment: @SureshS no. where are they?

Comment: var/log/  from Magento root directory

Comment: @SureshS Nothing related found in logs.

Comment: @kashish, getting any solution ?

Comment: @Dhaval Tried a lot of things. Still not working.

Comment: module is available in system -> configuration -> advance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove the entry `Learning_GreetingMessage` in `setup_module` table of the database used by Magento and then enter `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` command again in the root directory of Magento.

Answer (score 0):

The script you have posted is a `InstallData` script. This will only add data to a current table and not create a new table. The standard approach here would be to create a script `InstallSchema` script that would then do the table creation.

Have a look through `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Setup/InstallSchema.php` to see how Magento does this but the basic idea is.

1. Get the table name from the config,
2. Add the table to the database,
3. Add columns to the table,

The following is a "basic" example.

```
public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $installer = $setup;

    $installer->startSetup();

    /**
     * Create table 'catalog_product_entity'
     */
    $table = $installer->getConnection()
        ->newTable($installer->getTable('catalog_product_entity'))
        ->addColumn(
            'entity_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            ['identity' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
            'Entity ID'
        )
        ->addColumn(
            'attribute_set_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
            null,
            ['unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'default' => '0'],
            'Attribute Set ID'
        )
        ->addColumn(
            'type_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            32,
            ['nullable' => false, 'default' => 'simple'],
            'Type ID'
        )
        ->addColumn(
            'sku',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            64,
            [],
            'SKU'
        )
        ->addColumn(
            'has_options',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
            null,
            ['nullable' => false, 'default' => '0'],
            'Has Options'
        )
        ->addColumn(
            'required_options',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
            null,
            ['unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'default' => '0'],
            'Required Options'
        )
        ->addColumn(
            'created_at',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
            null,
            ['nullable' => false, 'default' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT],
            'Creation Time'
        )
        ->addColumn(
            'updated_at',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
            null,
            ['nullable' => false, 'default' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT_UPDATE],
            'Update Time'
        )
        ->addIndex(
            $installer->getIdxName('catalog_product_entity', ['attribute_set_id']),
            ['attribute_set_id']
        )
        ->addIndex(
            $installer->getIdxName('catalog_product_entity', ['sku']),
            ['sku']
        )
        ->addForeignKey(
            $installer->getFkName(
                'catalog_product_entity',
                'attribute_set_id',
                'eav_attribute_set',
                'attribute_set_id'
            ),
            'attribute_set_id',
            $installer->getTable('eav_attribute_set'),
            'attribute_set_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::ACTION_CASCADE
        )
        ->setComment('Catalog Product Table');
    $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
    $installer->endSetup();
}
```

Comment: I've also added `InstallSchema.php`. I've followed all steps of tutorial mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

**To Create Table "greeting_message" First you need to create InstallSchema.php file**

Try below code :

**InstallSchema.php file.**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $table = $setup->getConnection()->newTable(
            $setup->getTable('greeting_message')
        )->addColumn(
            'custom_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            ['identity' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
            'Custom Id'
        )->addColumn(
            'message',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            [],
            'Message'
        )->setComment(
            'Greeting Message'
        );
        $setup->getConnection()->createTable($table);

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

**installData.php file**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface {

    /**
     * 
     * Install Data in greeting_message table
     *   
     */
    public function install( ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context ) {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $tableName = $setup->getTable('greeting_message');

        if ($setup->getConnection()->isTableExists($tableName) == true) {
        $data = [
        [
            'custom_id' => '1',
            'message' => 'Happy New Year'
        ],
        [
             'custom_id' => '2',
            'message' => 'Marry Christams'
        ],
        ];
        foreach ($data as $bind) {
                $setup->getConnection()->insert($tableName,$bind);
            } 
        }
         $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

**Basically InstallSchema is used for creating table and its structure
And InstallData is used for insert data into table.**

For more refrence refer this link - http://inchoo.net/magento-2/setup-scripts-magento-2/

Comment: I've already added both the files. You asked only for `InstallData.php`, so , I pasted it's output only. sry!

Comment: @kashish no worries , do one thing create separate module and copy both the file which i have added here and it will work for you

Comment: Is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: @kashish well compare with my code ,  i always prefer code module as reference i have taken this code from magento core modules and used many times and its working well .

Answer (score 0):

```
$ php bin/magento module:disable Learning_GreetingMessage
```

Now from Db table "setup_module" and remove entry "Learning_GreetingMessage"

Now enable and upgrade the magento

```
$ php bin/magento module:enable Learning_GreetingMessage
$ php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

And now you can check the DB